# Display error if no checkbox is checked in checkbox group

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

How do I display an error message with Foundation 5's Abide HTML5 form validation library when no checkboxes are checked within the same checkbox group?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to write your own abide validator, but it is quite simple.

Working example: [CodePen link](http://codepen.io/Akarienta/pen/xbXmJw?editors=101)

JavaScript

```
$(document).foundation({
    abide: {
        validators: {
            checkbox_limit: function(el, required, parent) {
                var group = parent.closest('.checkbox-group');
                var min = group.attr('data-abide-validator-min');
                var checked = group.find(':checked').length;
                if (checked >= min) {
                    group.find('small.error').hide();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    group.find('small.error').css({
                        display: 'block'
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<form data-abide>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 column">
         <h4>Select your favourite vehicles</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns checkbox-group" data-abide-validator-min="1">
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-abide-validator="checkbox_limit" value="car" />
            car
         </label>
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-abide-validator="checkbox_limit" value="train" />
           train
         </label>
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-abide-validator="checkbox_limit" value="bicycle" />
            bicycle
         </label>
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-abide-validator="checkbox_limit" value="ferry" />
            ferry
         </label>
         <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-abide-validator="checkbox_limit" value="plane" />
            plane
         </label>
         <small class="error">You have to check at least one vehicle.</small>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice example.