# Foundation Abide : Custom defined patterns/validations not firing on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation, zurb-foundation

I am new to foundation abide validation. Till now i was using patterns & validations defined in abide. The onblur event was getting fired & error messages were getting displayed properly.
Today, i defined my own patterns and validations

```
$(document).foundation({
abide: {
    validate_on: 'manual',
    patterns: {
        positive_numbers_only: /^\d+$/,
        telephone_number: /(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}/,
        alphanumeric_spaces: /^[\w\s]+$/
    },
    validators: {
        checkbox_limit: function (el, required, parent) {
            "use strict";
            var group = parent.closest('.checkbox-group');
            var min = group.attr('data-abide-validator-min');
            var checked = group.find(':checked').length;
            if (checked == min) {
                group.find('small.error').hide();
                return true;
            } else {
                group.find('small.error').css({
                    display: 'block'
                });
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

The validations are firing properly on click of submit button but not on blur.
I am assuming the onblur event is not getting fired due to custom validation.

Note: I am using two buttons & have created a shadow submit button. On click of the button, I am triggering the shadow submit button's click event.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I *really hope* you're not actually doing this with name fields like in the fiddle. Names should *not* be validated, or you're going to have a lot of unhappy users who can't enter their names.

Comment: @AlexisKing hahaha...no i am not validating with names. It is just a basic example i came up with as my actual code is difficult to segregate. You can check the patterns i am using in the code i placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890023/display-error-if-no-checkbox-is-checked-in-checkbox-group)

The issue that i faced is, onblur was not working for me as i had checkbox in different divs. Check this -

```
<div class="row collapse">
     <div class="small-16 columns">
          <div class="row collapse">
               <div class="small-16 columns">Do you agree to our terms & conditions?</div>
               </div>
               <div class="row collapse checkbox-group" data-abide-validator-min="1">
                    <div class="small-3 columns">
                         <label for="cbYes">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="cbYes" value="Yes" data-abide-validator="checkbox_limit" />Yes
                         </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small-3 columns end">
                        <label for="cbNo">
                              <input type="checkbox" id="cbNo" value="No" data-abide-validator="checkbox_limit" />No
                        </label>
                        <small class="error">Please agree to our terms & conditions.</small>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have created a fiddle. [Check out](http://jsfiddle.net/thanawalad/L894vk66/8/)

So to overcome the onblur issue, i modified the foundation.abide.js file.

I have provided comments so anyone can understand where i have made the changes.

Hope it helps.

Learn more about Foundation Abide in the most simplest way from [here](https://thanawalad.wordpress.com/foundation-abide/)